# Unity2D Different Screen Resolution Problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is a game I made on Unity, but my game does not support different screens. I searched it online but all solutions contain "canvas" but I do not use canvas in my project.
my game works in 16:9 landscape resolution

What can I do about it

[1280x720 screen resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXyF2.png)

[2960x1440 screen resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Ofj.png)

Comment: There are two ways to deal with this. You can either use more than one Sprite to cover up your background. Or you can set Draw Mode to Tiled, to repeat your texture when you change its size.

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/cl6ocNh) is a screenshot of what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a script and attach it to the background that changes its dimensions using the resolution in use.

Example :

```
int width = Screen.Width;
int height = Screen.Height;

transform.localScale = new Vector3(width, height, tranform.localScale.z);
```

Just edit the code and use Vector2 for 2D objects.

Comment: Hey, don't you think that Screen.height and width return screen size in pixel rather than Unity Unity.